# Unable to execute an oracle update statement within perl

Tags: perl, oracle, execute

I have a problem in a perl script that I'm writing. When I run the script it hangs after prepare(). I've tried to run the update statement from SQL Developer and it works fine.

I've also tried to print out all parameters and they are correct.

What am I missing here?

```
my $upd = 'update ngs.pp_subscr_data set address=?, city=?, postalcode=?, kennitala=?, email=?, firstname=?, lastname=?, last_upd=systimestamp where snb=?';
my $s = $dbh->prepare ($upd) || exitError(-9802, 'Couldn\'t prepare update statement.');
$s->execute($addr, $city, $pcode, $ktala, $email, $fname, $lname, $snb) || exitError(-9803, 'Couldn\'t execute statement: ' . $s->errstr);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does it still hang if you change `||` to `or`?

Comment: What happens if you write `$dbh->do('update … where snb=?', { RaiseError => 1 }, $addr, $city, $pcode, $ktala, $email, $fname, $lname, $snb);`?

Comment: what happens if you replace "exitError" with "die": ... || die ($DBI::errstr).  Also, do some session browsing on the Oracle side to see if update is running...and I assume you are doing a commit and disconnect as well

Comment: does hardcoding the parameters in the statement make a difference?

Comment: I tried all your suggestions with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, what version of Oracle?

Ok, I see couple of problems with your description.  When you say "hang", is it really a hang?  Could it be spinning?

Also, second, you say "... it hangs after prepare()".  Does that mean it hangs after you call prepare(), or after it returns from prepare()?

Is it hanging in the database, and your client program is waiting for a database call to complete?

You need to run the program, then look at V$SESSION, identify the SID that corresponds to the database session of your program, and see what it's doing.  Look at the EVENT column in V$SESSION.  Also, look at the STATUS column to tell if the session is currently in a database call (ACTIVE), or waiting for the client program to call the database (INACTIVE).

Report some information back, and I may be able to provide further insight.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Mark. My database version is Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bit. It returns from prepare() and then stops/hangs when calling execute(). When I run "select * from v$session" from sql developer I get ora-00942 error so I can't give you any information about the session status.